# Android Studio reorders view elements in layout xml when formatting

Tags: android-studio

I clean installed Android Studio, currently running Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738, built on August 31, 2022. Inside layout XMLs When hitting CTRL+ALT+L to format, or also when having the format-option checked in the commit-prompt before committing my changes to git, the IDE will reorder the View elements in my XMLs.

Since the order of View elements determines which View is drawn on top of the others, this causes issues. How do i disable this behaviour? I looked at the CodeStyle settings for XMLs but couldn't find any settings for this specific behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML there is the option "Set from..." on the top right corner. If that isn't set to "Android", this could be the problem.

Comment: That solved it, thanks alot. Nearly drove me insane.
Why would AndroidStudio select by default anything else than the Android preset tho in the first place...

Comment: Happy to help! That is some kind of bug that's existing for years now...don't know why this isn't really fixed by now.

Comment: Yea i have had it happen before and since i couldn't fix it i reinstalled, that helped back then. But i figured now that it returned again i would like a propper fix. Made me go nuts.